# Add a serial order column to my data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

| date | product | serial_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/01/2021 | A | 1 |
| 21/01/2021 | A | 2 |
| 1/10/2020 | B | 1 |
| 2/10/2020 | B | 2 |
| 3/10/2020 | B | 3 |
| 4/10/2020 | B | 4 |
| 3/12/2020 | C | 1 |
| 4/12/2020 | C | 2 |
| 5/12/2020 | C | 3 |
| 29/11/2019 | D | 1 |
| 30/11/2019 | D | 2 |

I have a data frame like this (but without the serial_column), I would like to add this column. The data is sorted by date and grouped by products. How could I add the serial_column column? I would like to do it with the package `dplyr` if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide your dataset using `dput(x)`.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(serial_column = row_number())`

Comment: My data set contains private information. But just as example imagine the iris dataset, I would like to add a new column which goes from 1 to n1 for setosa, from 1 to n2 for versicolor, and for 1 to n3 for virginica. I know how to do it with loops but I'm trying to find a more efficient and clean way.